# Is there a way to use weakly informative default prior distributions for multinominal regression models?

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution, logit, mlogit

Following Gelman et al. 2008, we can use e.g. in the case of complete separation, weakly informative prior distributions to estimate a bayesian logistic regression.

However I wonder, whether there is a way to do something similar for a multinominal regression (I have 3 outcomes). It would be awesome if there is something implemented for stata or r.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, only efficient samplers with normal priors (with large variances in the case of weak information) have been developed.

The relevant reference is:

> Polson, Nicholas G., James G. Scott, and Jesse Windle. "[Bayesian inference for logistic models using Pólya–Gamma latent variables](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2013.829001)." Journal of the American statistical Association 108.504 (2013): 1339-1349.

This methodology is implemented in the R package [BayesLogit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesLogit/BayesLogit.pdf).